# How can I cross apply a column value like ["xxxx","xxxx"] extracted from a SQL statement

Tags: json, sql-server

The TCARDS.IdMembers contains a JSON like this ["xxxx","xxxx"] and I want to cross apply it with what I already have. The second `CROSS APPLY` generates an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
> Incorrect syntax near 'JSON_VALUE'.

[Screenshot1:here's that value of the @JSON_TABLE VARIABLE. It has that [cards] Key whisch contains most of what I need as shown in the SQL statement below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Rfj.png)
[Screenshot2:This is the result of TCards but I want to break down the idMembers further and cross apply it. Note: I had to exclude the other columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0BGr.png)

```
 DECLARE @JSON_TABLE VARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @JSON_TABLE = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\X tasks\updated\Tue, 17 Aug 2021 14_40_18 GMT.json', Single_CLob)J
Select 
TCards.id,
TCards.idList,
TCards.idLabels,
TCards.idMembers,
TCards.idChecklists,
TCards.shortUrl,
TCards.customFieldItems,
TMem.Mm1
from OPENJSON(@JSON_TABLE)
    WITH(
        id varchar(500),
        cards Nvarchar(Max) as JSON
    ) AS TABLEA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TABLEA.cards)
    WITH(
        id nVARCHAR(50),
        dateLastActivity nvarchar(50) '$.dateLastActivity',
        idboard nVARCHAR(50) '$.idBoard',
        idChecklists nvarchar(max) '$.idChecklists' as json,
        idMembers nvarchar(max) '$.idMembers' as json,
        idLabels nVarChar(max) '$.idLabels' as json,        
        customFieldItems nvarchar(max) '$.customFieldItems' as json,
        shortUrl nvarchar(50) '$.shortUrl',
        idList nvarchar(50) '$.idList'
    ) as TCards
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TCards.IdMembers) 
   WITH(
      Mm1 nvarchar(50) JSON_VALUE(TCards.IdMembers, '$.[0]')
  ) as TMem
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us. Thank you.

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. I suspect you need a couple of calls to `OPENJSON`, but impossible to know.

Comment: Per the error message, that syntax is not valid. The `WITH` clause expects types, paths and an optional `AS JSON` clause, you cannot insert arbitrary expressions like `JSON_VALUE` (those have to be moved to the `SELECT`).

Comment: @Larnu my apologies for the all caps.  I have attached 2 screenshots. Please help. Jeroen, I need a cross apply. But based on the screenshots, If JSON_Value will do the trick please help me formulate the syntax properly. Thanks.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you, @D.P.OL'RACE . We can't copy that image into our IDE. What's worse is the image truncates the data we can see. Take the time to make is consumable using DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Depends what you want, if it's always just one item in the array you could change the second `OPENJSON` to this `idMembers nvarchar(100) '$.idMembers[0]'`. If you want another join with multiple rows then you will need `OPENJSON`

Comment: @Charlieface. You are the man! Thank you very much! But if in case, for multiple rows, what would the syntax be? .... Anyways, I should content with what you suggested as it is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have one object in each array, you can remove the third `OPENJSON` and change the second one to use a driect path `'$.idMembers[0]'`

```
Select 
TCards.id,
TCards.idList,
TCards.idLabels,
TCards.idMembers,
TCards.idChecklists,
TCards.shortUrl,
TCards.customFieldItems,
TMem.Mm1
from OPENJSON(@JSON_TABLE)
    WITH(
        id varchar(500),
        cards Nvarchar(Max) as JSON
    ) AS TABLEA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TABLEA.cards)
    WITH(
        id nVARCHAR(50),
        dateLastActivity nvarchar(50) '$.dateLastActivity',
        idboard nVARCHAR(50) '$.idBoard',
        idChecklists nvarchar(max) '$.idChecklists' as json,
        idMembers nvarchar(50) '$.idMembers[0]',
        idLabels nVarChar(max) '$.idLabels' as json,        
        customFieldItems nvarchar(max) '$.customFieldItems' as json,
        shortUrl nvarchar(50) '$.shortUrl',
        idList nvarchar(50) '$.idList'
    ) as TCards
```

If you really did want to break out the array, you would do it like this

```sql
Select 
TCards.id,
TCards.idList,
TCards.idLabels,
TCards.idMembers,
TCards.idChecklists,
TCards.shortUrl,
TCards.customFieldItems,
TMem.Mm1
from OPENJSON(@JSON_TABLE)
    WITH(
        id varchar(500),
        cards Nvarchar(Max) as JSON
    ) AS TABLEA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TABLEA.cards)
    WITH(
        id nVARCHAR(50),
        dateLastActivity nvarchar(50) '$.dateLastActivity',
        idboard nVARCHAR(50) '$.idBoard',
        idChecklists nvarchar(max) '$.idChecklists' as json,
        idMembers nvarchar(max) '$.idMembers' as json,
        idLabels nVarChar(max) '$.idLabels' as json,        
        customFieldItems nvarchar(max) '$.customFieldItems' as json,
        shortUrl nvarchar(50) '$.shortUrl',
        idList nvarchar(50) '$.idList'
    ) as TCards
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TCards.IdMembers) 
   WITH(
      Mm1 nvarchar(50) '$'
  ) as TMem
```

If you leave out the `WITH` block, you instead get a `key/value` pair where `key` is the array index, and `value` is the object

Comment: I can't thank you enough @Charlieface. This means so much to me, man. I'm new to JSON and it's been splitting my head for almost 2 weeks now until I remember to ask a question. God Bless Always.